# Verilog $finish does not stop simulation

Tags: verilog

I've stumbled across a not so serious problem in Verilog + TCL. I wrote a TCL script that does `run -all`. In my module testbench, there is a call to a `$finish` at the end, but somehow when simulating, it does not stop and continues.

The `$finish` is inside an `initial` block. Other than that, there is also an `always` block which is not sensitive to anything that is used to generate the clock.

I'm not sure why it won't stop, but I suspect that the `always` block may have something to do with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$finish` terminates the simulation. Please focus some code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it. As far as I got, it was due to a compile option that I included in `vlog`, which was `-refresh`. I removed it and everything is working fine.

Thanks.